# Custom processor + DBCPConnectionPool for SQL Server : driver jar not loaded

Tags: jdbc, apache-nifi

I have created a controller service to connect to a test db.[image]

I have a custom processor that reads data from SQL Server, the mock tests, the build and the deployment to NiFi succeed. The processor runs into error, maybe the nar dependency scope is at fault or ... ?

I am unsure The pom for processor and the nar projects are as follows :

processor pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
<groupId>com.datalake</groupId>
<artifactId>CDCNiFi</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>nifi-NiFiCDCPoC-processors</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
<artifactId>nifi-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
<artifactId>nifi-utils</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
<artifactId>nifi-dbcp-service-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
<artifactId>nifi-processor-utils</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- Third-party -->
<dependency>
<groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
<artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
<version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
<version>2.8.7</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Testing & Cross-cutting concerns -->
<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
<artifactId>nifi-mock</artifactId>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
<artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

nar pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
<groupId>com.datalake</groupId>
<artifactId>CDCNiFi</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>nifi-NiFiCDCPoC-nar</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>nar</packaging>
<properties>
<maven.javadoc.skip>true</maven.javadoc.skip>
<source.skip>true</source.skip>
</properties>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.datalake</groupId>
<artifactId>nifi-NiFiCDCPoC-processors</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
            <artifactId>nifi-standard-services-api-nar</artifactId>
            <type>nar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
<groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
<artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
<version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
<scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

The issues :

The SQL Server JDBC jar is , probably, not loaded at runtime, the app.log has the following error :

```
2017-03-09 15:04:06,074 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-1] c.s.d.processors.SQLServerCDCProcessor SQLServerCDCProcessor[id=ad9de403-015a-1000-2b40-7efbfdb049b1] Process or SQL exception in <configure logger template to pick the code location>
2017-03-09 15:04:06,080 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-1] c.s.d.processors.SQLServerCDCProcessor 
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'
at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool.getConnection(DBCPConnectionPool.java:252) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.StandardControllerServiceProvider$1.invoke(StandardControllerServiceProvider.java:177) ~[na:na]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.getConnection(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.datalake.processors.SQLServerCDCProcessor.onTrigger(SQLServerCDCProcessor.java:244) ~[nifi-NiFiCDCPoC-processors-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27) [nifi-api-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1099) [nifi-framework-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:136) [nifi-framework-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:47) [nifi-framework-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:132) [nifi-framework-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_71]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_71]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_71]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_71]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_71]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_71]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_71]
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1429) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool.getConnection(DBCPConnectionPool.java:249) ~[na:na]
... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
at org.apache.nifi.nar.InstanceClassLoader.findClass(InstanceClassLoader.java:117) ~[nifi-nar-utils-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
at org.apache.nifi.nar.InstanceClassLoader.loadClass(InstanceClassLoader.java:98) ~[nifi-nar-utils-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
at org.apache.nifi.nar.InstanceClassLoader.loadClass(InstanceClassLoader.java:82) ~[nifi-nar-utils-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1420) ~[na:na]
... 22 common frames omitted
```

- In the controller service, I do not see my custom processor in
  'Referencing Components'(it says 'no referencing components')
- Right now, I have hard-coded the 'Database Driver Location(s)' but in
  production, I would like the controller to pick up that from the
  classpath(somehow, is it possible?)

*****Edit-1*****
As suggested by Mahendra, I did the following :

- Without any changes to the existing pom.xml files, added the dependency (sqljdbc4, 4.0) to both, the build and deployment succeeded but the jdbc driver error persisted
- The 'Database Driver Location(s)' kept as 'file:///'. Same error
  [image]
- Added the sqljdbc4.jar in NiFi/lib and the driver error vanished(getting other errors but those will be taken in a different thread). **Note** that the controller service still doesn't show the processor as 'referenced component'.
- The java version

  java -version
  java version "1.8.0_121"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

Isn't there a way to avoid adding the sqljdbc4.jar in lib, I mean third-party dependencies like fasterxml etc. are behaving properly, is this an issue with my configuration or some problem with the sql server maven repos. ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DBCPConnectionPool controller service for SQL Server, jdbc exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42854840/dbcpconnectionpool-controller-service-for-sql-server-jdbc-exception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@kaliyug,

**EDIT 1:**

1.if you declared DB class name is **"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"**.You should add below maven dependency in pom like below.,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
    <version>4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

2. Or If you want's to use in production environment you can specify driver database location in controller service like below.

   `file:///C:\DBLocation\sqljdbc42.jar`

3.Or you can just copy the **"sqljdbc42.jar"** directly into **NiFi\Lib** directory.After copied the jar,you should restart NiFi Services.At runtime ,SQL jar automatically Loaded when it search for DB ClassName in Nifi\Lib directory.

Please let me know if you have face any issues.

Comment: I have added the outputs that I got based on your suggestions, can you check the 'Edit-1' in the original answer ?

Comment: Can you share your java version?

Comment: Added, can you check the Edit-1 again ?

Comment: If your jdk version is 1.8 then you can't use sqljdbc4 jar

Comment: Use sqljdbc42.jar because your java version is 1.8.
Look at this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/system-requirements-for-the-jdbc-driver

Comment: Can you check my Edit-1?

Comment: I will proceed, for now, to add the jar file to the NiFi lib. Will post a separate question for the alternate ways.

Comment: Keep in mind any jars added directly to NiFi lib directory will be on the classpath of all NARs. This case is probably ok, but if the JAR had a class in the same package and same name as something a NAR was using, it would cause problems for the NAR.

Comment: The Maven coordinates in this answer are older than the coordinates in the question, and they point to the JDBC 4.0 driver, not the JDBC 4.2 driver.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel
I had tried the official Microsoft 4.2 maven version, still got the issue :

<dependency> <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId> <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId> 
   <version>6.1.0.jre8</version> </dependency>

Comment: @KaliyugAntagonist In that case I suggest you carefully check the classpath to check if there isn't an older version of the driver also present.