# DBCPConnectionPool controller service for SQL Server, jdbc exception

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-nifi

NiFi 1.1.1 tested on both Windows 7 and RHEL 7.

The background thread is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42765471/jdbc-failing-in-custom-processor).

I have created a DBCPConnectionPool controller service pointing to a SQL Server db, I am able to fetch data from a table and write it to the local disk(ExecuteSQL -> ConvertAvroToJSON -> PutFile).

My code:

```
public byte[] getMaxLSN(Connection connection, String containerDB) {
    String dbMaxLSN = "{? = CALL sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn()}";
    byte[] maxLSN = null;

    try (final CallableStatement cstmt = connection.prepareCall(dbMaxLSN);) {

        cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.JDBCType.BINARY);
        cstmt.execute();

        if (cstmt.getBytes(1) == null || cstmt.getBytes(1).length <= 0) {

            System.out.println("Coudln't retrieve the max lsn for the db "
                    + containerDB);

        } else {
            maxLSN = cstmt.getBytes(1);

        }
    } catch (SQLException sqlException) {
        System.out.println("sqlException !!!");
        sqlException.printStackTrace();
    }

    return maxLSN;
}
```

[image]

The challenge arises when I use the pool as a property in my custom processor. In the processor's code, I need to invoke a function in the db but this lands into a **SQLException pointing to the JDBC driver. Note that the same driver functions properly in a standalone Java code**(provided in the background thread to avoid cluttering this post) and I get the return value from the function. I suspect that the Controller Service is not configured properly - it can execute select queries but when a code invokes a function, it throws an Exception. What am I missing ?

```
Process or SQL exception in <configure logger template to pick the code location>
2017-03-17 09:25:30,717 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6] c.s.d.processors.SQLServerCDCProcessor 
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Coudln't retrieve the max lsn for the db test
    at com.datalake.processors.SQLServerCDCProcessor$SQLServerCDCUtils.getMaxLSN(SQLServerCDCProcessor.java:692) ~[nifi-NiFiCDCPoC-processors-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.datalake.processors.SQLServerCDCProcessor.getChangedTableQueries(SQLServerCDCProcessor.java:602) ~[nifi-NiFiCDCPoC-processors-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.datalake.processors.SQLServerCDCProcessor.onTrigger(SQLServerCDCProcessor.java:249) ~[nifi-NiFiCDCPoC-processors-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27) [nifi-api-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1099) [nifi-framework-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:136) [nifi-framework-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:47) [nifi-framework-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:132) [nifi-framework-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_71]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_71]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: registerOutParameter not implemented
    at java.sql.CallableStatement.registerOutParameter(CallableStatement.java:2613) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
    at com.datalake.processors.SQLServerCDCProcessor$SQLServerCDCUtils.getMaxLSN(SQLServerCDCProcessor.java:677) ~[nifi-NiFiCDCPoC-processors-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2):

*"java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: registerOutParameter not implemented"* Your code is using a feature not available in the driver.

Specifically, based on the stacktrace, your driver is calling `registerOutParameter(int parameterIndex, SQLType sqlType)`, which was introduced in JDBC 4.2 (Java 8). This method has the following default implementation in the `java.sql.CallableStatement` interface:

```
default void registerOutParameter(int parameterIndex, SQLType sqlType)
    throws SQLException {
    throw new SQLFeatureNotSupportedException("registerOutParameter not implemented");
}
```

Where the `throw` is line 2613 in `java.sql.CallableStatement`, which matches the stacktrace.

As [this method **is** implemented](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/blob/master/src/main/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerCallableStatement42.java#L32) in the latest version of the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver, you are either using an older version, or the objects of the driver are wrapped in a proxy that doesn't support JDBC 4.2.

I suggest you upgrade to the [latest version of the driver](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/latest), currently v6.1.0. As [another question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42697854/custom-processor-dbcpconnectionpool-for-sql-server-driver-jar-not-loaded) suggests you use maven, then you should should ensure the **new** Maven coordinates for the driver (they changed it when they open-sourced the driver):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
</dependency>
```

If the problem persist, then as `com.datalake.processors.SQLServerCDCProcessor` is your own code (as shown in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42765471/jdbc-failing-in-custom-processor)) , you should just change it to not call `registerOutParameter(int parameterIndex, SQLType sqlType)`, but the older `registerOutParameter(int parameterIndex, int sqlType)`.